# Tech Choice : JAX-WS vs Spring-WS from Existing WSDL

Tags: spring, web-services, hibernate, wsdl, jax-ws

I have few WSDLs defined and now have to create Web services out of it which will interact with Database.

Need suggestions on choice of technology.

#### For Web-Service

- (simple one, no WS-* features to be used like WS-Security etc at present)
- **JAX-WS**---------: I think this would suffice my purpose.
- **Spring-WS**-----: Could be used just for now, plus for future enhanced usage. But looking at the tutorials, it feels very complicated (have to train two new team member). Thoughts?

#### Database Interaction

- **Hibernate**-------: Almost made my mind for this.
- Which one of JAX-WS vs Spring-WS would be more easily integrated with hibernate.

Comment: What application server you are going to use?

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same and opted to use pure jax-ws see the article: http://java.dzone.com/articles/web-services-jax-ws-vs-spring

there is a good example with maven pom, for quick project bootstrap.